# Firebase cloud messaging (FCM) get old Notification every restart app

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an iOS application for my company and I am integrating Firebase Cloud Messaging to my application. I receive the notifications in background or foreground. Every time I restart my application, I get an old notification that appears every time. As if there was no confirmation from my application that this notification is received by the user. FCM sends it back to me in a loop. Do you have an idea for this problem?

//Init

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await MyDbModel().initializeDB();
  initFireBase();
  runApp(myApp());
}

void initFireBase() async {
  print("------------- InitFireBase -------------");
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    await _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(message);
  });
}

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  // I update my DB
}
```

Comment: Do you use `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()`? If so, could you share your code from this method?

Comment: Those are different methods, though... Perhaps read my own question on this subject, to get some guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73722164/if-i-tap-local-notification-while-app-is-terminated-the-data-from-the-remotemes No answer though, unfortunately...  but maybe it answers YOUR qn?

Comment: Another qn: Do you log in to the app before the repeated message comes? Or you are already logged in and just start up the app from terminated?